# How to resize top panel font size

Tags: unity, gnome, fonts

I followed [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40415/how-do-i-resize-gnome-shell-top-bar) but still didn't help.

[image]

Comment: What is the 0S??

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Comment: Use Ubuntu.css file  `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/Ubuntu.css` 0r what ever shell theme you want

Comment: Awesome, it helped!

Comment: You can comment below so you can have a big tick.